# Retrieve posts count to view

Tags: php, cakephp, view

## Error: Call to a member function find() on null

I'm still kinda new to cakephp but I'm getting along with it ...
How can I retrieve the users post count to the view?

Or do I actually retrieve it in the view? if so how?

In my UsersController I have

```
    public function view()
        {
            $postcount = $this->Post->find('count');
            debug($postcount);
            die;
        }
```

But I get this error:

Error: Call to a member function find() on null

Comment: You probably did not load the `Post` model in your `Users` controller. Do you have a relationship between `User` and `Post`? If so, post it. And which version of cakephp are you using?

Comment: Thanks for responding!

I fixed it by placing in my UsersController

public $uses = array('User', 'Post');

(being both the Models I need to use in the controller, which I had forgotten to include)